# discord.py + PostgreSQL | 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, postgresql, discord, discord.py

Создал команду для бота в дискорде, которая показывает магазин ролей. До этого роли были добавлены в магазин (в нашу базу данных) и проблем не возникло. Собственно, проблема возникла при выводе этих ролей из базы данных при использовании команды `shop`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop(
        role_id BIGINT,
        id BIGINT NOT NULL,
        cost BIGINT
    )""") # Создаем базу данных магазина

# Shop | Магазин
@client.command(aliases = ['shop', 'магазин'])
async def __shop(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Магазин ролей')

    query = cur.execute(f"SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = {ctx.guild.id}")
    for row in query:   # Ошибка указывает на эту строчку (149), скорее всего что-то не так строчкой выше
        if ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]) != None:
            embed.add_field(
                name = f"Стоимость **{row[1]}** :small_red_triangle_down:",
                value = f"Роль {ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]).mention}",
                inline = False
            )
        else:
            pass
    
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

`File "C:\Users\Михаил\Desktop\боты\Хидэко\bot.py", line 149, in __shop`
   `for row in query:`
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Вот команда, которая заносит данные вы базу данных

```py
# Add Shop | Добавить в Магазин
@client.command(aliases = ['addshop', 'add-shop', 'добавитьмагазин'])
@has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def __add_shop(ctx, role: discord.Role = None, cost: int = None):
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.author}**, не указана добавляемая роль | d!addshop role cost')
    else:
        if cost is None:
            await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.author}**, не указана стоимость роли | d!addshop role cost')
        elif cost <0:
            await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.author}**, стоимость роли не может быть отрицательной')
        else:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO shop VALUES ({}, {}, {})".format(role.id, ctx.guild.id, cost)) # Добавить в базу данных айди роли, айди сервера и стоимость
            con.commit()

            await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅') # Добавление реакции
```

Comment: Все элементарно просто - или неправильно составлен `sql`-запрос или в таблице нет такого значения, поэтому в `query` записан `None`. Соответственно, если перевести название ошибки на русский -  тип данных `None` не может быть итерирован)

Comment: @DeNRuDi, прикрепил к вопросу команду, которая отвечает за внос информации в таблицу. Можете, пожалуйста, проверить правильность написания запроса?

Comment: ну прежде всего ваш код уязвим на sql-иньекции, почитайте об этом здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/45128973/14774145 (не знаю как в `postgresql` но в sqlite подобный код был бы точно уязвим) - используйте вместо метода `format` соответствующее форматирование для `postgre` . А вот насчет запроса сказать не могу - по идее все верно, и запись должна быть в базе, но у вас почему-то возвращает курсор `None`.  Уверены, что запись действительно есть в базе?

Comment: Да, запись должна быть в базе, я запустил pgAdmin для проверки и внес информацию, показатели отобрали внос информации в таблицу

Comment: аа так допишите еще к `sql`-запросу `fetchone()` если нужно выбрать 1 запись или `fetchall() если нужно выбрать все найденные записи`, или же `fetchmany(size=2), если нужно выбрать только 2 найденные записи`. То есть - `cur.execute('Запрос').fetchone()`

Comment: Наконец! Все заработало, как нужно. Спасибо Вам огромное!